# Laravel 5.4 - Payload is invalid with get attribute

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5.4

I use Laravel 5.4.

I have encrypted values (*access_token* & *access_token_secret*) in database.

I use accessor to get decrypted values.

My **PHP** code in **Twitter** model:

```
public function getAccessTokenAttribute($value) {
    return decrypt($value);
}

public function getAccessTokenSecretAttribute($value) {
    return decrypt($value);
}
```

But, I get error:

> The payload is invalid.

My "payload" is been setted in **.env** file.

My code to get values:

```
{{ $twitter->access_token }} & {{ $twitter->access_token_secret }}
```

Comment: This means that the value from the datatabase you're trying to decrypt is invalid. Can you show how you encrypted it and perhaps give an example value?

Comment: I encrypt the access_token & access_token_secret in column of 500 chars (varchar) with encrypt() function.

Comment: If I dd() the encrypted value, it works! But when I use my function, not...

Comment: Depending on your token length it could easily go over 500 characters and get cut off in the database. Check your records to be sure. If you remove the accessors and do `decrypt($twitter->access_token)` does it work?

Comment: The chars length is 277 chars. I just solved the problem. A value in the database was not encrypted.